# How to print PHP array to HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I am trying to output the array $Movies as an HTML table, here's the function:

```
function print_movies($table= 'Movies'){
    $db= $GLOBALS['db'];

    $Movies = get_info('Movies');

    print_r($Movies);

    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>Movie Title</th>
                <th>Year Released</th>
                <th>Was it a book?</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
            </tr>"

    for($i=0;$i<count($Movies);$i++)){
        ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $Movies[$title]; ?></td>
        <tr><td><?php echo $Movies[$year_released]; ?></td>
        <tr><td><?php echo $Movies[$is_book]; ?></td>
        <tr><td><?php echo $Movies[$genre]; ?></td>
        <?php
    }

    echo "</table>";
    ?>
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<?php
    print_movies($Movies);
?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $Movies[$i][$title]; ?>`

Comment: You're also missing closing semicolon after the header row `</tr>";`

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: @Set Sail Media only `</tr>`

Comment: I am 99% sure I was asked to do this exact task when I went to college

Comment: you should look into `foreach`, it will change your life.

Comment: `$i++))` <-- What does the second `)` close?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus This might be one of those assignments where they plant a bunch of mistake into the code, and you have to find and fix them.

Comment: First of all thank you all for the help. The "for" loop seems to be the problem, the table is being constructed but none of the data is being output, only empty boxes under the "Movie Title" column, after I took MonkeyZues' advice

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP openning and closing tags were not located properly.

You also forgot to put a semicolon after your first echo.

```
<?
    function print_movies($table= 'Movies'){
    $db= $GLOBALS['db'];

    $Movies = get_info('Movies');

     print_r($Movies);

    echo "<table border='1'>

    <tr>
    <th>Movie Title</th>
    <th>Year Released</th>
    <th>Was it a book?</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    </tr>";

     for($i=0; $i<count($Movies); $i++){ 
         ?>
    <tr><td><? echo $Movies[$title]; ?></td>
    <tr><td><? echo $Movies[$year_released]; ?></td>
    <tr><td><? echo $Movies[$is_book]; ?></td>
    <tr><td><? echo $Movies[$genre]; ?></td>
        <?
        }

    echo "</table>";


    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the array is setup but this should work.

```
<tr>
    <?php
    foreach($Movies as $movie){
        echo "<td>".$movie[$title]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$movie[$year_released]."</td>";
        //...
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```